# Mysql user problems

Tags: mysql

I try to setup remote access to a mysql server. I think all steps are done but when I test the connection I get this error

Access denied for user ‘jv80’@‘vmi955628.contaboserver.net’ (using password: YES)

The problem is the hostname, that come from when the vps was setup. I have changed bost hosts and hostname file years ago and cant find out where the host come from. Is there any other place it can come from?

TIA
Anders Yuran

Comment: Random comment: you can tweak `/etc/hosts` so it converts `vmi955628.contaboserver.net` to the IP address of your MySQL server. That's a terrible solution, but may give you enough access to fix things up

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04. Have Webmin as CP

Comment: The hostname should not prevent you from signing in from outside the server if your `CREATE USER` statement used `%` for the domain and the firewalls are configured to allow external connections.